# Linq retrieving index

Tags: c#

I need to retrieve the index of my items as I select them in Linq, is this the best way to do it? I don't like the fact that I have to declare a variable outside of my Linq statement.

```
List<int> ApplianceIds = new List<int>();
ApplianceIds.Add(6);
ApplianceIds.Add(3);
ApplianceIds.Add(4);
ApplianceIds.Add(5);
ApplianceIds.Add(6);
ApplianceIds.Add(7);
ApplianceIds.Add(2);

int ind = 0;

var y = (from a in ApplianceIds
        let index = ind++
        select new {Appliance = a, Index = index}).ToList();
```

Comment: ApplianceIds is a `List<T>`, you already have the index. You can use a for loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd do this;

```
var y = ApplianceIds.Select ((a,i) => new { Appliance = a, Index = i } ).ToList();
```

Comment: This. Most of the LINQ extension methods have overloads that provide the index.

Comment: This does answer the question. However, why use LINQ to get the index of items in a `List<T>`???

Comment: For demonstration purposes. Maybe the real scenario that prompted this question doesn't have the data coming from a list. Or maybe he's composing a query to pass to another function. The indexed overloads exist for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

ApplianceIds is a List, you already have the index. You can use a for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<ApplianceIds.Count; i++)
{
    // i is your index
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help him get the index as he's selecting in LINQ, as he asked.

Comment: Right, this is just another "[Must LINQ all the things!](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/x-all-the-y)" question. Sorry guys, LINQ isn't the best answer to everything.

Comment: It may have been a simplified example to demonstrate what he wants to do. Using a for loop causes you to lose the composability that LINQ gives you.

Comment: Even so, the only additional property his anonymous type has is Index, something `List<T>` already has.